# System freezes during boot process

Tags: windows-7, freeze

i have a machine running Win7 Ultimate. It was running fine, then it just froze - all the stuff i was doing was still on the screen, but mouse and keyboard input was ignored, any animation that was happening on the screen stopped, the machine literally just froze.

So i rebooted (power off button), from then on the machine will reboot, but it ultimately freezes again. The instance when this happens will vary - i have made it as far as the Windows login screen, but mostly it will do the POST, then give me the option to press F1 to continue or Del to enter BIOS settings (but of course pressing a key has no effect - it's frozen!).

I have disconnected everything not necessary for the boot process, the only peripheral that remains attached is the keyboard. (even the network cable is disconnected). Prior to this the machine was operating fine. The install of Win7 is only 2 days old, and it was a fresh reinstall (i.e. not an upgrade or repair).

Can anyone give me an indication of what may be wrong here?

I'm not sure if this question should be here or on SuperUser, please migrate it if i have chosen the wrong board.

Comment: This is better suited for Superuser.  Moderators will relocate it for you.

Comment: 1 vote for faulty main memory

Answer (score 1):

Well, because it even freezes after the bios screen, we know it is definately a hardware issue.

The problem is a freezing issue could be any piece of hardware in the machine.

Get some spare parts and start swapping out, easy ones first. Ram, CDrom, video card if it is seperate from the Motherboard, Power Supply.

To many possibilities, sorry

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Like Tom said, its most likely hardware problems.

It might be heat related. Let the machine cool down for 30 minutes, and see if you get further.

It could also be memory issues, try running a memtest or diagnostics.